# Can't connect Mongodb to Node.js : throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to connect a Mongoose with my Node.js but it always show this error. I am following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) tutorial to create a authentication system. After writing the server.js file and trying to fix a problem in the routes.js I got an error and I don't know why, please help.

Here are my code and error :

***server.js***

```js
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

// require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

***routes.js :***

```js
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    //...
};
```

***package.json***

```js
{
  "name": "node-authentication",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express" : "~4.0.0",
    "ejs" : "~0.8.5",
    "mongoose" : "~3.8.1",
    "passport" : "~0.1.17",
    "passport-local" : "~0.1.6",
    "passport-facebook" : "~1.0.2",
    "passport-twitter" : "~1.0.2",
    "passport-google-oauth" : "~0.1.5",
    "connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",

    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.0"
  }
}
```

***database.js***

```js
// config/database.js
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'your-settings-here' // looks like mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/Mikha4ot

};
```

***error***

```js
The magic happens on port 8080
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ouestcharlie/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:25)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at emit (events.js:175:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ouestcharlie/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ouestcharlie/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Comment: What is inside `'./config/database.js'`? Can you share the file as well please?

Comment: That file is empty for now. They fill it after the command "node server.js" works well.

Comment: You're using this file to connect to MongoDB. So when the file is empty, there is not url property in the JSON file and therefore an error when connecting to MongoDB. Are you absolutely sure the file is empty?

Comment: Sorry here is the code of database.js **// config/database.js
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'your-settings-here' // looks like mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/Mikha4ot

};**

Comment: Can you connect to the database using the Mongo shell? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/

Comment: when I enter the command line "service mongodb status", I get the message : "bash: service: command not found"

Comment: That is not really an answer to the question...

Comment: Really sorry, just reread your question ! And the answer is "no I can't"

Comment: You should be able to connect to your database through the Mongo shell. So maybe your database is offline/behind a firewall. Concerning the error, I still think there is something wrong in your `database.js`. The url you are connecting to, is `undefined:27017` which is obviously failing.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose.connect() expects parameters in the format:

`"mongodb://<hostname>/<databasename>"`

instead, it's getting what's configured in your database.js, which is the following:

`"your-settings-here"`

I'm guessing that that's going wrong. Just fill out a decent connection url in database.js, such as: "mongodb://localhost/my-test-db" (please replace with the proper values), and this error will go away.

Comment: I replaced 'your-settings-here' by 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:8080/test' which I think is right, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Is the error exactly the same? Also referring [undefined:27017]? Same line-numbers everything? Also, are you sure about the port-number? it seems that the default port-number is 27017, if that's the port you're using you can just leave it out. Port 8080 is almost certainly wrong, since your application (not MongoDB) is already running on 8080 - You are running a mongodb on localhost right?

Comment: No, now I have "Error: connection closed" instead. And yep, I'm running mongodb on localhost

Comment: Perhaps an authentication problem? As suggested by ThomasBormans before, could you try the MongoDB shell, to confirm that your connection-information is correct? - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/

Comment: I tried to run "mongo --shell" or "cd <mongodb installation dir>" (for the installation"), and I get this message : "bash: mongo: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum needed to connect the myapp database running locally on the default port (27017). If the local connection fails then try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Sometimes issues may arise when the local hostname has been changed. [source : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html]

I had the same error. I reinstalled mongoDB but it didn't work.

I solved my issue by using the following url to connect to localhost.
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database-name')`;